# Include a scrollbar inside html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, popup

I have a pop-in inside my html code can i display with a mouseout event.

I make `$("body").mouseleave(function(){});` but when my mouse pass on scrollbar my script is trigger.

Is there a way to include the scroll bar so that its hover does not trigger the script?

i try :

```css
html{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper{
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
       <div class="wrapper">
         ... content ...
         start<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         .<br/>
         end<br/>
       </div 
    </body>
</html>
```

and it's work, thank guys

Comment: Try `$(document).mouseleave(function(){});` instead

Comment: It has the same behavior :/

Comment: can you include some code, maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: Wrap your content inside a container with `overflow: scroll` You will have 2 scroll bars though, unless you hide your body / html overflow with hidden.

Comment: With body inside ? It's a structure with many table / tr / td, i can't show here, because it's not mine :/

Comment: When i hidden my html (or body) overflow, and i add a wrapper, my overflow is hidden, my new scroll bar appear, but i can't scroll into my page.